# Running Helm Command in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm 3 and I would like to deploy myapp via Helm and Jenkins.I can able to run `kubectl` command in Jenkins pipeline but when stage runs `helm --upgrade install` command run I received an error. What might be the missing point?

**Console Output**

```
+ export KUBECONFIG=****
+ KUBECONFIG=****
+ kubectl config use-context c1
Switched to context "c1".

+ helm upgrade --install my-app -f values.dev.yaml --namespace dev
```

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/my-app@tmp/durable-8c9e7261/script.sh: line 4:
>   helm: command not found

Comment: Did you install Helm?

Comment: yes but my k8s cluster and jenkins run different server.. Should I do anything in Jenkins server?

Comment: Meanwhile,my-app is the release name, should I define also my chart name when run helm -install command?

Comment: Can you just do "helm version" first to verify you can execute helm command from your Jenkins pipeline? The output should be the version of both client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm is not installed on the node where jenkins is running the pipeline. Make sure that you install helm in all nodes including master or slave jenkins nodes.